# Is there a way to force a project to reload *all* textures?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

I work with a lot of materials that utilize external textures and frequently I want Blender to reload all of the external textures associated with the current project, but the only way I know to do this is to shut down the project and then re-open it. Is there a way I can to this with the project open?

I know that in the Shading or UV Editing tabs you can click on a node and hit "Alt+R" to reload the texture for the selected Texture node, but that's time-consuming. Any suggestions? Thanks! Blender 3.0, Windows 11

Answer (score 5):

There is an add-on that I use that comes with Blender called TexTools. This has a ton of useful features! The one's I use most are reloading all textures (like what you're wanting), and "rectify" which will try it's best to layout a wonky looking UV map into a square. Perfect for pipes/cushions/etc.. Hope this helps! [image: TexTools]

Comment: I can't find this add-on anymore (Blender 3.5). Must've been removed from the built-in add-ons?

Comment: It may have, I don't have that version installed yet, but you can find the file here: https://github.com/SavMartin/TexTools-Blender/releases

Answer (score 4):

Well, I need to clarify LWS SWL's answer. He has talked about functionality of Amaranth toolset add-on

You can enable it in user preferences, add-ons tab:

[image]

Then the add-on is enabled you can simply save and reload scene, that forces all libs and textures to be reloaded:

[image]

It is the easiest way to do this in one click

Answer (score 3):

If you press shift-ctrl-w, that will save and reload the file (including textures).
It is also under file>save & reload.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your responses! Very helpful. The Amaranth toolset "Save & Reload" button is a dream. Thanks!